# How to get UIPageViewController to not clipToBounds

Tags: ios, paging, uipageviewcontroller

I need to overlay a UIView over a UIPageViewController and was hoping it would let me turn off the clipsToBounds and then resize the interactive bounds area to a smaller height and place another view on top of the non-interactive/non-clipped region.

Unfortunately the UIPageViewController resizes the childViewController in some way where it will clip it no matter what.

What I want is something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I can find no samples of doing anything like this and did try to use the UICollectionViewController instead with paging but it doesn't have the smooth gaps between pages like the UIPageViewController does.

Comment: Would adding the overlay as a subview to the UIPageViewController's superview not work?

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing to get it to "work" but clipsToBounds is not doing what I would expect for the controller. I used a parent controller that resizes the contents of the page view controller's child and left the page view controller at full screen.

Answer (score 5):

View of UIPageViewController has another UIView (more precisely _UIQueuingScrollView) in the subviews hierarchy before actual view of your childViewController. So, to disable clipsToBounds you should do something like that:

```
UIPageViewController *pageViewController = ...;
pageViewController.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
[[pageViewController.view subviews].firstObject setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

Comment: the second page doesn't appear until I swipe the uipageviewcontroller tho with this solution

Comment: @coolcool1994 , just use the code in my answer below, cheers

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me in Swift:

```
pageViewController.clipsToBounds = false
pageViewController.view.clipsToBounds = false
for view in pageViewController.view.subviews {
    view.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Similar to Vitaly's answer, but uses a loop to ensure that all subviews are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

## Curiosity ...

If the page view controller is set to the "curl" mode, in fact it anyway has NO clipping. Who knew?

## The fix ...

Thanks to Brian and Vitaly

```
class FixedPVC: UIPageViewController {
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        view.clipsToBounds = false
        for v in view.subviews { v.clipsToBounds = false }
    }

}
```